# SpeechRecognitionEngine is always recognizing a word of the choice even if its wrong

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech

I am working with speech recognition in C# using the `SpeechRecognitionEngine` library, I have set the word "start" as a word to recognize(Choices):

```
Choices choices_start = new Choices("start");
GrammarBuilder grBuilder_start = new GrammarBuilder(choices_start);
Grammar grammar_start = new Grammar(grBuilder_start);

SpeechRecognitionEngine speech = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
speech.LoadGrammar(grammar_start);
speech.SpeechRecognized += RecognizerSpeechRecognized;

private void RecognizerSpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in e.Result.Words)
    {
        switch (word.Text)
        {
            case "start":
                Console.WriteLine(word.Text);
                speech.UnloadGrammar(grammar_start);
                speech.LoadGrammar(grammar_using);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine(word.Text);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that no matters what I say, it always recognize the "start" word, any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

This is how the algorithm works. As long as you give it only one choice, it will only return you the given word. You need to give it more text variants to look for.

For example, if you want to recognize an arbitrary text, you could use [DictationGrammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar.aspx) instead of simple grammar. Please note that the list of word will be still limited, it will not be able to recognize very rare words. But the list will be large.

If your task is to look for a specific word in a continuous stream, you need to look for keyword spotting engine, not the speech recognition engine. Microsoft doesn't provide keyword spotting engine functionality. You can build one using open source engines like [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net)